# Freeswitch "real" response to api chat?

Tags: freeswitch

I'm sending an sms message like this over esl (telnet, java client, various methods all yield the same results)(numbers are all dummies):

api chat sip|13215555555@6.50.120.201|internal/2395555555@6.50.120.200|test message

This works fine with valid numbers.  If we put in an invalid number somewhere we may see something like this in the sip trace indicating a problem:

U +0.745829 6.50.120.200:5060 -> 6.50.120.201:5060
SIP/2.0 484 Address Incomplete.
...

...however over the esl socket we get the same response event no matter what, just "sent".  Also, when we bind to the esl port and attempt to spit out every message possible (no filters), we see most of what comes through a sip trace, but again not this bad result sip packet for some reason.  It's like freeswitch is filtering out this specific packet from esl.

Is there a way over esl to probe raw sip messages so that we can test for such a packet manually, or some other way of seeking the final async result?

Thanks in advance!